# Protocol https not supported

Tags: android, c++, curl, openssl, libcurl

I built libcurl from sources, for android with a prebuilt openssl lib (using `--with-ssl=$OPENSSPATH`). The build was succeeded with no errors.

When I'm trying to make a https request I receive "Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl". But in `curl_version_info` https is contained in the protocols list:

```
02-17 13:26:07.780: D/wrapperLogNotification(8930): Curl PROTOCOLS:
02-17 13:26:07.780: D/wrapperLogNotification(8930): dict
02-17 13:26:07.780: D/wrapperLogNotification(8930): file
02-17 13:26:07.780: D/wrapperLogNotification(8930): ftp
02-17 13:26:07.780: D/wrapperLogNotification(8930): ftps
02-17 13:26:07.780: D/wrapperLogNotification(8930): gopher
02-17 13:26:07.780: D/wrapperLogNotification(8930): http
02-17 13:26:07.780: D/wrapperLogNotification(8930): https
02-17 13:26:07.780: D/wrapperLogNotification(8930): imap
02-17 13:26:07.780: D/wrapperLogNotification(8930): imaps
02-17 13:26:07.780: D/wrapperLogNotification(8930): pop3
02-17 13:26:07.785: D/wrapperLogNotification(8930): pop3s
02-17 13:26:07.785: D/wrapperLogNotification(8930): rtsp
02-17 13:26:07.785: D/wrapperLogNotification(8930): smb
02-17 13:26:07.785: D/wrapperLogNotification(8930): smbs
02-17 13:26:07.785: D/wrapperLogNotification(8930): smtp
02-17 13:26:07.785: D/wrapperLogNotification(8930): smtps
02-17 13:26:07.785: D/wrapperLogNotification(8930): telnet
02-17 13:26:07.785: D/wrapperLogNotification(8930): tft
```

Is this a build issue, a call issue, or something else?

Comment: Is OpenSSL linked as a static library to cURL? Or is cURL using the OpenSSL shared object? If its the shared object, then you should experience unexplained failures and errors. See the answer to [Changing OpenSSL library in Android app for HttpClient](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28392326/608639).

Comment: Openssl is linked as a static library to curl.

Comment: @user3605225 Did you find a solution of this issue? if yes please explain i am facing same issue.