# AES_KEY and AES_BLOCK_SIZE cannot be resolved

Tags: android-ndk, openssl, aes

I wish to run a C program(works fine using gcc) on android. I have installed ndk for eclipse and have setup the basic things correctly. I have linked openssl library(.so files) to the project. Methods such as `AES_set_encrypt_key` aren't facing any issue but I am getting error at `AES_KEY/AES_BLOCK_SIZE` saying `type/symbol cannot be resolved`. How to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you `#include` crypto/aes/aes.h ?

Comment: You will likely have problems in this configuration. For details, see [Changing OpenSSL library in Android app for HttpClient](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28341215).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. There was a problem with the `extern` statements in `aes.h` header file in eclipse IDE. As I was using it in a C code, these aren't required. Once I removed them, the problem got solved!