# undefined reference error in ndk android project using static library

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, linker, openssl

I'm creating a native android application in Android Studio. I downloaded [GitHub eighthave/openssl-android](https://github.com/eighthave/openssl-android) project. I only added the row `APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a` to `jni/Application.mk` as its first row.

When I run "ndk-build" in command line it compiles `libcrypto.so` and `libssl.so` which I copied to my project's `jni`, `libs/armeabi-v7a` and `jniLibs/armeabi-v7a` folders. I also copied the `include` folder to my project's `jni` folder.

My project Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH              := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE            := libcrypto
LOCAL_SRC_FILES         := libcrypto.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE            := libssl
LOCAL_SRC_FILES         := libssl.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE            := sec
LOCAL_SRC_FILES         := main.cpp application.cpp
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS          += -fexceptions -frtti -std=c++14
LOCAL_LDLIBS            := -llog -landroid -lEGL -lGLESv1_CM
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES        := ${ndkDir}/sources/android/native_app_glue
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES        += $(LOCAL_PATH)/include # openssl include folder

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES  := android_native_app_glue libcrypto libssl
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,android/native_app_glue)
```

When I run "ndk-build" from command line on my project it creates a `sec.so` file in the `libs` folder and copies the OpenSSL shared libraries next to it.

If I try to create an apk with Android Studio it throws an error:

> ```
> undefined reference to 'DH_new'
> ```

at this row:

> ```
>  DH dh = DH_new();
> ```

I can only compile the project in Android Studio if I do not use any functions from the openssl project. And if I do so then I can see all shared libraries in apk's "lib/armeabi-v7a" folder so it can find all the libraries.

So probably the problem could be in my `build.gradle` file so here it is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.3"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId = "com.example.sec"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 16
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
        }
        ndk {
            moduleName = 'sec'
            toolchain = 'clang'
            stl = 'c++_static'
            cppFlags.addAll(['-Wall', '-std=c++14', '-fexceptions'])
            cppFlags.add("-I" + file("src/main/jni/include").absolutePath)
            ldLibs.addAll(['log', 'android'])
        }
        sources {
            main {
                jni {
                    dependencies {
                        project ':nativeactivity' linkage 'static'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled = false
                proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.txt'))
            }
        }
        productFlavors{
            create("arm7") {
                ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

And here is my Application.mk but I do not think it helps much:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions -frtti -std=c++14
APP_STL := gnustl_static
```

I also tried to create static libraries from OpenSSL project but still got errors. I use gradle-experimental:0.7.0 dependency.

Can please someone help me to figure it out what could be wrong with my project.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't use OpenSSL directly as a shared object. You have to write a wrapper shared object that exposes all of the OpenSSL functionality you want. Your wrapper shared object links against the static version of OpenSSL. For details, see [Changing OpenSSL library in Android app for HttpClient](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28341215). You might have link problems when linking your wrapper shared object to the static version of OpenSSL, but that's a different problem.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem.
It seems that the only thing I missed is link against the shared libraries in the build.gradle file.

Like this:

```
ldFlags += "-L${file(path/to/libssl.so)}".toString()

ldLibs += ["ssl"]
```

Comment: I don't get it.  I don't see ldFlags mentioned in the gradle-experimental specs.